# JQuery navigation with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

There are a few questions about JQuery navigation with ajax, but I don't see answers I'm looking for, so here's my take.

I have a simple webpage using JQuery Mobile, which is using JQM's "navigation system", i.e. hashtag on one side, plus it recognizes that form was submitted and does ajaxization internally. In other words it is enough for me to put href="some_url" in A tag, or to make a simple form with submit button, and JQ Mobile does the rest.

Now I need to do exactly the same thing, but for a desktop version of the site. JQ Mobile-like navigation system would be ideal (but it is not usable for "normal" HTML ajax since it cleans HTML of all non-mobile-compatible tags) since then the server-side logic would remain the same, and I would only change the "layout" (mobile/desktop) to show different pages to the users on different devices.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Thank you,

Bozo

Comment: Update: maybe http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ is part of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for a framework similar to jQuery Mobile for web AND mobile without any luck.

What we implemented instead:

To handle page navigation/hash change we used:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/.
Use this to show/hide `data-role="page"`

Ajax form handling can you handle with [jQuery submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

To load HTML into your pages instead of following link, you can do this with [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

On top of this we provide different mobile and web views. This can be done by using [media queries](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#mq) in the client, or by detecting device type server side.

Comment: If it's not a problem, can you please copy paste one example of a .submit() and one example of a .load() in the context of what you described in your answer above? Thanks.